# How do i meteor.call a method with an object or array as an argument?

Tags: meteor

this is a button click event that calls a server-side method:

```
Template.newTeam.events
    "click .btn-save": ->
        form={}
        $.each $('#newTeamForm').serializeArray(), ->
            form[this.name] = this.value;

        Meteor.call 'saveTeam', form, (error, result) ->
            if error.error == "team-exists"
                alert "A Team with this name already exists."
            else
                console.log 'saved'
                Router.go('list-teams')
```

when btn-save is clicked the error below is displayed

is it that the Meteor.call does not accept an object or array as an argument. I can call the method with separated arguments but I wanted to know if it is possible to just send and array or object.

```
[Log] Exception in delivering result of invoking 'saveTeam': http://localhost:3000/client/views/dashboard/teams/teams.coffee.js?ace17a4ab13667bbc2fa272b80dc3018fb860a52:10:16 (meteor.js, line 883)
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:973:27
_maybeInvokeCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:3853:21
receiveResult@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:3873:30
_livedata_result@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:4926:22
onMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:3718:28
http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:2713:19
forEach@[native code]
forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:18
onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:2712:15
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:152:27
_dispatchMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:1137:23
_didMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:1195:34
onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:1342:28
```

help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

This is the saveTeam method. the data successfully passes to this method. but i still see that error.

```
Teams = new Mongo.Collection('teams');

Meteor.methods
    saveTeam: (team) ->  
        if ! this.userId
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-logged-in", "Must be logged in to post a comment.")
        if Teams.findOne({name: team.name})
            throw new Meteor.Error("team-exists", "A team with this name already exists.")
        else
            Teams.insert
                createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
                name: team.name,
                description: team.description,
                visibility: team.visibility
```

Comment: You can pass an object or array as a parameter in method. The problem is somewhere else. Try to show more code - saveTeam method.

Comment: I dont understand your code man, could you make it more clear and structure?

Comment: I think the method throws an exception when you call it. For example, I think you should use `Meteor.userId ()` instead of `this.userId` in methods.

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` didn't solve the issue. The data does get passed to the method, but the code below `Meteor.call 'saveTeam'` does not execute.